# Combining PHP into a Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

Basically I'm struggling adding PHP into

```
<a style="cursor:pointer;" onClick="location.href='https://www.example.com/go/'">LINK</a>
```

My code right now:

```
        <a style="cursor:pointer;" onClick="location.href='https://www.example.com/go/
                                            
<?php $randomid = rand(361, 370);
echo '' . $randomid . '&name=john'; ?>

        '">Link</a>
```

But the above doesn't work. When you click, nothing happens.

I have also tried this way:

```
<?php $randomid = rand(361, 370);
echo '<a style="cursor:pointer;" onClick="location.href='https://www.example.com/go/' . $randomid . '&name=john'">Link</a>'; ?>
```

But since the javascript contains `''` they confict with PHP's html code `''`.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Well you would have one "level" of nested string delimiters less to deal with, if you simply used the `href` attribute to link somewhere, like that is _supposed_ to be done, instead of using JavaScript for the same functionality for no apparent reason.

Comment: `doesn't work` isn't a useful description. When you run the PHP code, what does the generated link look like? You can examine it in your browser tools to see what it looks like and spot the mistake. But CBroe is right, using JS click to make a link redirect makes no sense when you can just use the link in the normal way..

Comment: The "doesn't work" probably results from the arbitrary whitespace you introduced there. The resulting text literal inside the single quotes will go over several lines, and that simply is a JavaScript syntax error.

Comment: Hey CBroe, I have a very good reason to use javascript link... I can't use a static a href link. I'm doing javascript link to avoid bots clicking on links.

Comment: It would be a pretty useless bot if it didn't just click on the anchor anyway to be sure. You might stop a crawler from following the link perhaps, but not a full bot, I suspect

Comment: I agree, I want to stop a crawlers (search engines) and other crawler bots. As I want only real human clicks to count. As for "a full bot", you probably meant bots who click anywhere on the page, or bots who clicks via selectors? I doubt I will have such..

Comment: Yes or ones which use a headless browser so that JavaScript will run when they click. A more basic crawler would only deal with the raw HTML, but I think these days search engines are more sophisticated

Comment: I read somewhere that bots don't click on buttons with `<button></button>`, maybe that would be the best solution for my situation?

Comment: What bots do is whatever the bot wants to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So ... :) like this - you either use href or use a function onclick... not supposed to be together but this will work:

```
$randomid = rand(361, 370);?>
<a href="https://www.example.com/go/<?php echo $randomid;?>&name=john" style="cursor:pointer;">Link</a>
```

From what I read in the comments you are looking for a js function... not an a href link eh?

So how about this:

```
<?php
$randomid = rand(361, 370);?>
<a onclick="myFunction('<?php echo $randomid;?>');" style="cursor:pointer;">Link</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction(randomid){
        window.location.assign("https://www.example.com/go/"+randomid+"&name=john");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, the javascript  code is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use this one it's also working.

```
<?php
    $randomid = rand(361, 370);
    echo '<a style="cursor:pointer;" href="https://www.example.com/go/'.$randomid.'&name=john">Link</a>';
 ?>
```